# how to insert multiple `product` and `quantity` in mysqli using foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql

I want to insert multiple `product` and `quantity` of each product in `mysql` using `foreach loop` but code below insert only the last product I input in `input field`. I use jquery to add more field so i can input more `product` and quantity of each product.

this is the jquery i use to add more input field in my form **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gtWu3/)**

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
     //process the form   

     $qtys = array($_POST["product_description"] => $quantity = $_POST["quantity"]);
     foreach($qtys as $item => $qty){

     $date = $_POST["date"];
     $customer_name = $_POST["customer_name"];
     $status = $_POST["status"];

     $query  = "INSERT INTO orders (";
     $query .= "date, customer_name, product_description, quantity, status";
     $query .= ") VALUES (";
     $query .= "'{$date}', '{$customer_name}', '{$item}', {$qty}, {$status}";
     $query .= ")"; 
     $order_set = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
     if($order_set){
       redirect_to("index.php");
     }

     }



  } else {
    // failed

  }


?>
```

My Form

```
<form action="order.php" method="post">
  <div class="newOrder">
    <p><span>Date</span><input type="date" value="2014-12-01" name="date" /></p>
    <p><span>Name</span>
    <select name="customer_name">


     <?php
      while($customer = mysqli_fetch_assoc($customers_set)){  ?>

        <option><?php echo $customer['customer_name']; ?></option>

      <?php } ?>
      <?php mysqli_free_result($customers_set); ?>

    </select>

    </p>  


    <div id="input_fields">

    <p><span>Product Description</span>
    <select name="product_description[]">
     <?php
      while($product = mysqli_fetch_assoc($product_set)){  ?>

        <option><?php echo $product['product_description']; ?></option>

      <?php } ?>
      <?php mysqli_free_result($product_set); ?>
    </select>
    <input value="0" type="text" name="quantity []" />
    </p>

    </div>
    <a href="#" class="more">Add More Product</a>


    <p class="radio">
      <input type="radio" name="status" value="0" checked />For delivery&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <input type="radio" name="status" value="1" />For payment confirmation&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <input type="radio" name="status" value="2" />Reserved items&nbsp;&nbsp;
    </p>


    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Create Order" />   
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: do you get any errors ?

Comment: there no error but only one `$item` and `$qty` save in database

Comment: How you are defining the form?

Comment: @sgt edit my question and i add my form structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because you are redirecting at the end of the first loop - move the redirect out of the loop - and it should loop though and insert each one - Also the most obvious but i overlooked it that you are looping through an array that has only 1 element - since you are setting it right at the top $qtys - do a var dump on the $_POST and let me see what is being posted .

```
<?php

  error_reporting(E_ALL);
  if(isset($_POST['submit'])){


     $errors = array(); 

         $date = $_POST["date"];
         $customer_name = $_POST["customer_name"];
         $status = $_POST["status"];

     foreach($_POST['product'] as $key => $desc){
         // do this to other ones too
         $qty = filter_var($_POST['quantity'][$key], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
         $desc = filter_var($desc, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); 

         $query  = "INSERT INTO orders (";
         $query .= "date, customer_name, product_description, quantity, status";
         $query .= ") VALUES (";
         $query .= "'{$date}', '{$customer_name}', '{$desc}', {$qty}, {$status}";
         $query .= ")"; 
         $order_set = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
         if(!$order_set){
            $errors = $query; 
         }
     }// end of for each 

    if(empty($errors)){
        // no errors redirect to home page 

        header("Location: index.php");
    }

    // if it makes it here then there are errors. 
    echo ' Errors in the sql ---- ' ; 
    var_dump($errors); 
    echo 'POST VALUES';
    var_dump($_POST); 
  } 

?>












<form action="order.php" method="post">
  <div class="newOrder">
    <p><span>Date</span><input type="date" value="2014-12-01" name="date" /></p>
    <p><span>Name</span>
    <select name="customer_name">


     <?php
      while($customer = mysqli_fetch_assoc($customers_set)){  ?>

        <option value="<?php echo $customer['customer_name']; ?>"><?php echo $customer['customer_name']; ?></option>

      <?php } ?>
      <?php mysqli_free_result($customers_set); ?>

    </select>

    </p>  


    <div id="input_fields">

    <p><span>Product Description</span>
    <select name="product[]">
     <?php
      while($product = mysqli_fetch_assoc($product_set)){  ?>

        <option value="<?php echo $product['product_description']; ?>"><?php echo $product['product_description']; ?></option>

      <?php } ?>
      <?php mysqli_free_result($product_set); ?>
    </select>
    <input value="0" type="text" name="quantity[]" />
    </p>

    </div>
    <a href="#" class="more">Add More Product</a>


    <p class="radio">
      <input type="radio" name="status" value="0" checked />For delivery&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <input type="radio" name="status" value="1" />For payment confirmation&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <input type="radio" name="status" value="2" />Reserved items&nbsp;&nbsp;
    </p>


    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Create Order" />   
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer but still only one item save in my database

Comment: do a var_dump($_POST) and send me that data i will show you how to process it -

Comment: this show after I create order entry : `array(0) { }`

Comment: and / or the form names - if you want to hold and post multiple values under one name - the you would have to name="products[]"

Comment: when I change name="product_description[]" the `print_r($_POST)` show this `Array ( [date] => 2014-12-01 [customer_name] => Emelio Colibao [product_description] => Array ( [0] => Acid Ipil Ipil [1] => Centrosema ) [quantity] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 ) [status] => 0 [submit] => Create Order )`

Comment: there is no errors appear and it redirect to index.php but also no intries save in the database

Comment: My bad - try it now - should be OK -

Comment: still it redirect to `index.php` but no intry save in database by the way i update my question above and i put my form structure in my edit..

Comment: When you run it with error reporting on tell me what it says - i just added to updated code

Comment: there is no `errors` display it redirect to `index.php` after I click the submit button.

Comment: Just looked at your javascript - when you sent me the post values you had under - product description - but the new comment with the javascript creating them it is under product - Try the updated code should work fine - Which would explain why there were no sql errors - because the foreach never looped through any elements

Comment: Also in your javascript you are adding inputs as name-'products[]' and in the php you are using the name='product_description[]' use one or the other - then it will be fine

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66184/discussion-between-ratiorick-and-jhunlio).

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use input name as array

the error is that your data is over writtern  use `print_r($_POST)` to check for all values are posted

use

```
<input type="text" name="product []" />
<input type="text" name="quantity []" />

<input type="text" name="product []" />
<input type="text" name="quantity []" />

<input type="text" name="product []" />
<input type="text" name="quantity []" />
```

and your if gets you out to `index`

```
 foreach($qtys as $item => $qty){

     $date = $_POST["date"];
     $customer_name = $_POST["customer_name"];
     $status = $_POST["status"];

     $query  = "INSERT INTO orders (";
     $query .= "date, customer_name, product_description, quantity, status";
     $query .= ") VALUES (";
     $query .= "'{$date}', '{$customer_name}', '{$item}', {$qty}, {$status}";
     $query .= ")"; 
     $order_set = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
     // if($order_set){   
       // redirect_to("index.php");
     // }

     can use  "if(!$order_set)" instead

 }
```

Comment: this show in `print_r($_POST)` `Array ( [date] => 2014-12-01 [customer_name] => Emelio Colibao [product_description] => Array ( [0] => Acid Ipil Ipil [1] => Flemingia ) [quantity] => Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 3 ) [status] => 0 [submit] => Create Order )` and no entry save in database.

Answer (score 0):

Try with -

```
 $query  = "INSERT INTO orders (";
 $query .= "date, customer_name, product_description, quantity, status";
 $query .= ") VALUES ";
 $values = array();
 $date = $_POST["date"];
 $customer_name = $_POST["customer_name"];
 $status = $_POST["status"];
 foreach($qtys as $item => $qty){
     $values[] = "('{$date}', '{$customer_name}', '{$item}', {$qty}, {$status})";
 }
 $query .= implode(',', $values);
```

Answer (score 0):

As per this code I think there must be issu of **persistent connection**

please try this by closing connection after each insert. and also consider **redirect_to()** that is also wrong.